# I have a linux image how can I find somebody that will host it?

Tags: web-hosting, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

The image has a site running on php 4 using some archaic CMS + some version of My Sql + etc.

I need to find a host, but I am not sure if the hosting providers will host an old image

I don't know who the previous host was, just being handed the image by the previous developer.

PS : If there is an obvious solution that I am missing ( pardon my ignorance, I have not done this before, I am just a windows developer ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to look for a VPS that lets you use custom filesystem images. Otherwise, any managed dedicated server would allow you to do this. However, there are very few cases where you'd actually want to continue using PHP4 and an archaic CMS in a production environment.

You're better off migrating the content to a modern CMS running on the latest version of whatever programming language and RDBMS you're familiar with.

If it were a custom application and actually very well built, then you could simply port it to PHP5 and the latest version of MySQL. Depending on the size of the codebase, and how well developed it was (including how good the documentation is), it could be relatively easy to do this—if finding and configuring/customizing a suitable modern off-the-shelf replacement isn't any less work.

But in all likelihood, simply migrating the content to a modern CMS would be the most safe/sensible and economical thing to do.